# Using the terminal, what other ways can you delete a file?

Tags: command-line, deleted-files

Other than `rm`, what alternative methods will achieve the same result?

For example, moving a file to "trash" and securely emptying the trash bin. Or moving the file to `/dev/null`

Comment: `unlink` filename

Comment: @1"; Note that you cannot remove a file using `/dev/null`; the latter is primarily used to discard output from processes using redirection.

Comment: Overwrite with another file: `mv 16tons filename`

Comment: `find filename -delete`

Comment: Actually not an answer since the file remains but with `> filename` you can empty/truncate the file to 'trash' its contents

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of utilities that can delete a file, perl or other language interpreters are obvious candidates. If you have gcc, you can make yourself another one:

```
echo "main(int argc, char **argv) {return unlink(argv[1]);}" > myrm.c && gcc myrm.c -o myrm && ./myrm myrm.c
```

Comment: Love it! Let's call it `jit-rm` :D .

Answer (score 0):

The command will delete all the files inside `/foo` directory:

```
find /foo -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

1. Find all the files in foo directory
2. Execute the files that was found
3. Remove them one by one